# Unmark topic that is marked for deletion in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I have marked three topics for deletion using this command:

`kafka-topics --zookeeper localhost:2181 --delete --topic topic_name`

Now I can't use them and neither can I recreate them. How can I resolve this issue?

Either to delete them totally and then recreate them, or unmark the status for deletion.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you can restore it, if it is not yet deleted!

Log in to the Zookeeper prompt and use the `rmr path` command:

```
sudo ./zookeeper-shell.sh localhost:2181

rmr /admin/delete_topics/topic_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you list and see whether those topics are there?  In order to list:

`kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181`

> Deleting a topic is supported since 0.8.2.x. You will need to enable topic deletion (setting delete.topic.enable to true) on all brokers first.

Make sure you've done the change in the `broker config` file and then try deleting the `topics`.

Ref: [Is it possible to delete a topic](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/FAQ#FAQ-Isitpossibletodeleteatopic?)

I'm not sure whether you'll be able to unmark the ones you've marked for deletion. As far as I know you'd be able to delete it totally and recreate them.